# wdio - ERROR: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io

When I try to run tests with wdio I am getting `ERROR: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService`  It also says `Driver info: driver.version: unknown`

In my wdio.conf.js file, I have

```
seleniumArgs: {
        version: '3.141.0',
        drivers: {
            chrome: {
                version: '2.43'
            },
            firefox: {
                version: '0.23.0'
            }
        }
    },
    seleniumInstallArgs: {
        version: '3.141.0',
        drivers: {
            chrome: {
                version: '2.43'
            },
            firefox: {
                version: '0.23.0'
            }
        }
    },
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here, or what other information I could provide?  The full error is:

```
ERROR: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.141.0', revision: '2ecb7d9a', time: '2018-10-31T20:22:52'
System info: host: '<me>', ip: '<my_ip>', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6', java.version: '1.8.0_212'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help anyone, but the way I fixed this was to do `locate selenium` on my machine and just delete everything.  I wonder if global selenium was messed up or something?  After I did `npm install` in my repository again, the tests were able to run with ChromeDriverService.

Answer (score -1):

This error message...

```
ERROR: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.141.0', revision: '2ecb7d9a', time: '2018-10-31T20:22:52'
System info: host: '<me>', ip: '<my_ip>', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6', java.version: '1.8.0_212'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are trying to use *chrome=2.43* which is an **invalid** version.
- Your *chromedriver* version is unknown to us.
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=77.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/77.0.3865.40/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :
- Your *Selenium Client* version is *3.141.0* of *2018-10-31T20:22:52* which is almost **a** year older.
- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_111** which is pretty ancient.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *Selenium Client v3.141.0* , *ChromeDriver* and the *Chrome Browser*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v77.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=77.0.3865.40/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 77.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v77.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/77.0.3865.40/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.